# What is the cover art on this Administrator's companion book?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a copy of [Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Administrator's Companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735613672), and I can't figure out what the tool is on the cover.

Does anyone know what this is? [Cover for Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Administrator's Companion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bAaD.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a [bore hone](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=bore%20hone&x=0&y=0). For honing engine cylinders (where the piston goes).

Comment: +1 for knowing what a bore hone is... and what it looks like. P.S. If anyone has a picture of a Helsinki smash rod, I'd love to see it.